# Definition of uninitialized memory produces a "attempt to initialize memory" error

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

First of all, let's begin by saying I am an absolute beginner at assembly language, so there could be a very simple solution that I might not even be seeing/understanding.

My problem is the following: I am trying to create a basic addition program in assembly through nasm. So far, this is the code I've written (changed the comment semicolons to hashes):

```
#basic assembly file that takes 2 digits, adds them together and prints them on the screen via a function

global _start

section .data

    initString db "Please enter the first number:", 0x0a
    initStringL equ $-initString
    secondString db "Please enter the second number:", 0x0a
    secondStringL equ $-secondString
    resultString db "The result of the addition is:", 0x0a
    resultStringL equ $-resultString

section .bss
    
    num1: resb 0x400
    num2: resb 0x400
    num3: resb 0x400


BasicMath:

    #epilog
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp


    #print initString
    mov eax, 0x4
    mov ebx, 0x1
    mov ecx, initString
    mov edx, initStringL
    int 0x80

    #read input
    mov eax, 0x3
    mov ebx, 0x2
    mov ecx, num1
    mov edx, 0x400
    int 0x80

    #print secondString
    mov eax, 0x04
    mov ebx, 0x1
    mov ecx, secondString
    mov edx, secondStringL
    int 0x80

    #read second input
    mov eax, 0x3
    mov ebx, 0x2
    mov ecx, num2
    mov edx, 0x400
    int 0x80

    #addition
    mov al, num1
    add al, num2
    mov num3, al
    int 0x80

    #print resultString
    mov eax, 0x04
    mov ebx, 0x01
    mov ecx, resultString
    mov edx, resultStringL
    int 0x80

    #print actual result
    mov eax, 0x04
    mov ebx, 0x01
    mov ecx, num3
    mov edx, 0x400
    int 0x80    
    
    #prelog
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret


_start: 

    pushad
    pushfd

    call BasicMath

    popfd
    popad


    ;exit program
    mov eax, 0x1
    mov ebx, 0x0
    int 0x80
```

Now, when I put this through nasm, I get several dozens of "attempt to initialize memory" errors, and in the middle of them, one "invalid combination of opcode and operands", like so:

[image: Loop of errors when putting the file through nasm]

Now, I'm not sure at all about the actual addition part of the program, in particular the "mov num3, al" that might be complete gibberish, but I have no idea where the memory problem fits in all of this and what its cause is.

Comment: You forgot to switch to `section .text` before your `BasicMath` function. The invalid operand is likely the `mov num3, al` (you get the line number printed)  because [NASM Requires Square Brackets For Memory References](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.2.2). Note you need to use `[]` in the preceding two lines as well.

Comment: Thank you! It's not producing any bug now, but I am faced with another problem: the program displays nothing when it should show the result of the addition to the user, ie. what is in the 3rd variable. I see values changes in gdb, so the addition must be taking place, but somehow nothing is returned. I also tried adding square brackets to the "num3" of the "print actual result" section, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: You need to convert the result to text. Subtract 0x30. Also your result is 1 digit, not much point in printing 0x400.

Comment: What do you mean by "subtract 0x30"? As for the 0x400, I just assumed that it would allow the user to enter a very large number without producing an error. I am, after all, a complete beginner :)

Comment: `0x30` is the ascii code of `0`. Consult an [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com). Your code only works for single digits, and the result must be a single digit too. It won't magically work for large numbers just because you allocated a big space.

Comment: Ah, I get it now, thank you!